# What to do to change usernames in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I am using JIRA v4.4 and I want to change usernames in JIRA. But it seems that I have to install add-on to update usernames. After a search in google I found that the most people recommend to install [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/version/272) add-on. Up to now it is okay, but what to do next? How can I change user names with Script Runner add on now? Or is there a better way to change user names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found that there are built in scripts, and in those scripts you can  use Renames a user ID script. Because I had an error, those scripts were not showed up before. By giving From User ID and To user ID you can update the name. Moreover Jira team will add [this feature](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-4588) in the next 12 months so after that don't have to use add-ons for username update operation.

Comment: I know it comes with scripts, but as I said because of an error it didn't show up and I didn't even mention Atlassian. Please make sure that you read it correctly.